# How do you copy a file from Windows to a VMware virtual hard disk (Ubuntu)?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I have VMware Player, and I run Ubuntu with it on my Windows 7 system. Now I want to copy some files from my Windows folders into the VMware virtual hard disk, so that I can view these files on Ubuntu.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 8):

Mount a shared folder that's on the Windows host onto Ubuntu. That way you don't even need to copy them.

Go to *Virtual Machine » Virtual Machine Settings » Shared Folders*.

Comment: +1 Didn't realize there was a setting in VMware for Shared Folders. Works for Windows to Windows VMs as well.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do is to install the VMware Tools in Ubuntu, then you are able to drag the file into the Ubuntu VM.

To install VMware Tools, you need to switch to Ubuntu, then go to the VMware menu *VM » Install VMware Tools*, and then follow the instructions to finish the installation.

Answer (score 2):

If no suggestions works, put your files in a FAT32 formatted pendrive. 
You'll see Mass Storage Device icon in bottom right corner of you VM window.
Right click press Connect(Disconnect from Host).

Works!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't manage to configure a shared folder, or just really want a separate copy inside the VM, you can also just rightclick->copy in the host and paste in the guest. At least that works here with VMware player, windows 7 (host) and linux mint (guest).

Comment: Your virtual machine should have the vmware tools installed in order enable this simple copy/past, otherwise it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your linux machine (ubuntu) in vmware. Click on "Places" and go to "Network" . Go inside "Windows Network" and go deeper and you will find "user" and then "Public" . This folder is nothing but your windows "Public" folder. You can use this folder as a shared folder between host and guest machine.

Comment: I can't get this to work.  Are you sure you aren't leaving something out (like configuring your Windows "Public" folder to be shared on the network)?

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Ubuntu in VMware. Click on `Places` and go to `Network`. Go inside `Windows Network` and go deeper and you will find `user` and then `Public`.

This folder is nothing but your Windows `Public` folder. You can use this folder as a shared folder between host and guest machine.